# Is there a way to tell a component not to wait for transitions on its children?

Tags: svelte

I have a form with many form controls and some of them have slide transitions, because some controls shouldn't be visible all the time.

The problem is that when I hide the entire form component, for example to replace it with another form component, it waits for the transitions on its children to end.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/391b3614fefb48c586f38291b2236fcc?version=3.51.0

Comment: Question should be self contained, please include relevant code *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

Buried in the docs there is a `local` transition directive: https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-transition

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/427c27bc20d44f0db6446b430f1882ab?version=3.31.0

Comment: It's not buried, it's even in the tutorial.

Comment: I thought it was buried because it should have been mentioned in the svelte/transition section, not in element bindings/transition:fn